# How to hide the bottom navigation bar in tabview?

Tags: swiftui

In the following `tabview` a navigation bar (I mean the tabs bar etc) appears in the bottom. How to hide it? I just wanna use the `tabview` as a hidden tool, I have a custom made navbar to make selection of the current tab. Removing `.tabItem {Text("Home")` also does not make the bar to hide.

```
TabView(selection: $TabSelectedItem) {
                    
                    Home()
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("Home")
                        
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                    
                    
                    Text("Tab Content 2")
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("Tab2") }
                        .tag(2)
                    
                }
```

Comment: You can use `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))` to hide it.

Comment: Why use a `TabView` at al thenl. Just use a `switch`

Comment: @Asperi It works thanks a lot, if you make it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` statement.

```
import SwiftUI

enum item {
    case home
    case tab2
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selectedItem: item = .home

    var body: some View {
        switch selectedItem {
            case .home:
                Home()
            case .tab2:
                Text("Tab Content 2")
        }
    }
}
```